# Should I salvage purged questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, copyright, copyright-infringement

An OP asked a question some time ago, then asked to be purged of the database because it revealed a bit of corporative information and was asked by their employees to do so. And the revision was destroyed, not even moderators know what was asked.

Now, the question is/was interesting, has a answer, it can't be/isn't covered by the Copyright rules (it was some file configurations for Apache) and I still have it in one of my tabs. Should I re-ask the question if I anonymize it? It's Stack Exchange, Inc. liable? If I can, where to draw the line?

Comment: Could any of the upvoters please explain what this question means?

Comment: @Won't I didn't upvote for that reason, but I *think* it means that the OP here saw a question.  The OP of that question deleted it because it had private **corporate** info, and now he wants to repost it as a new question without the private info.  But that's only a guess.

Comment: @psubsee2003 not the OP, but the SE team purged from the databases at OP request, you know, an irrecoverable state. The other parts of your guess are fine.

Comment: @Braiam: a link would be super helpful.  Something tells me that nothing needs to be done here.  It sounds like you are asking if you should repost someone else's (anonimizied) question, which would be a big no.

Comment: @Won't why don't you make that an answer? And link *to what* exactly?

Comment: Presumably a link to whatever it is you are considering re-asking.

Comment: I don't know what Won't expect to see in the like @JonEricson but here it goes http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126369/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ... depends. You can't/won't always know why a post has been removed, so there is no way to make any sort of blanket statement regarding liability.

Is it a good question? Can you reliably determine the correct answer? Is it helping people? If you answered "yes" to all of these questions, you could probably re-ask it in a more anonymized form, but depending on why it was removed in the first place, that might not be enough to prevent another deletion.